# How to add legend to a plot diagram in R

Tags: r, plot

I have this dataframe made out of `col1` and `col2` data. What I need is add a legend that shows `col2` values.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c( 1, 2, 3,1,2,4,6,6),
             col2 = c( 4, 5, 6,4,5,6,4,6))

     mycolors = c('red','yellow','blue')
plot(df[c("col1", "col2")],col=mycolors)
legend(1, 95,legend=c("col2"),
   col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
```

Comment: You are drawing your legend at `y=95` but your  visible plot only goes to `y=6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had four small mistakes:

- The location of your legend is outside the grid. Try `4.5,6.0` instead.
- `legend=` should be a list of labels, probably unique. Use `unique(df$col2)`
- `col=` should be the same colors. Use `col=mycolors`
- You should add the symbol of the dots in the plot. That is - `pch=1`

To sum up:

```
legend(4.5, 6.0, legend = unique(df$col2), col=mycolors, pch = 1)
```